# Database inserts slow down the larger the table gets

Tags: sql-server, performance

I am experiencing issues with database inserts slowing down the larger the table gets. I am inserting around 1.3 million records where the first 100,000 are inserted at a reasonable speed, but then the inserts get gradually slower.

The table starts off empty, and does have three foreign keys and five indexes which I have read may cause a slow down with every insert having to be re-indexed. Can I confirm this is a possible cause of the issue?

Is there anyway I can improve this performance hit by disabling the indexing after insert statements and doing it again at the end (without dropping the index)?

Does anyone have any further suggestions for improving the performance.

I am using SQL Server, and it is on my second hard drive.

Comment: I think it's quite common for indexes and constraints to be dropped and then recreated again after bulk inserts.

Comment: Can you post the table schema and all the indexes?

Answer (score 0):

It could be many problems.  See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421(v=sql.105).aspx) for MSDN recommendations on optimizing bulk inserts. However I would try limiting the batches to say 10,000 or 100,000 rows and see how that goes. If it helps a lot then you should spend some time to figure out your best batch size. I've seen lots of times where that is an issue because of

a) How the transaction log grows and people don't understand how it affects the log and how the log needs to keep growing.

b) How memory is affected for indexes on a large amount of rows.  From the article on batches [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188267(v=sql.105).aspx)

> SQL Server optimizes the load automatically, according to the batch
>   size value, which may result in better performance. In general, you
>   should make the batch size as large as practical. Typically, the
>   larger the batch size, the better the performance of the bulk-import
>   operation. A few exceptions exist, however. If one or more indexes
>   exist on the target table, then a larger batch size might put memory
>   pressure for sorting.

There are other notes in the batches article about how changing your batch size could improve your performance and why, these are just a couple examples (and the ones I see the most often).